# VBA Dynamic Filtering and Copy Paste into new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a vba script that will filter on two columns, column A and column D. Preferably, I want to create a button that will execute once I have chosen the filter criteria. Sample of input data below.

```
 Sub Compiler()
  Dim i
  Dim LastRow As Integer

  LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:J6768").ClearContents

     For i = 2 To LastRow
          If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Values = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, "B").Values And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Values = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, "D").Values Then
             Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A" & "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" + Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
          End If
     Next i

End Sub
```

[Sample Data to run vba script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cGDSK-8vEJGJjvsyKjrNUUssQOnVWyx5qOT2ArDZmuc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered the question I was asking, I tried to work with Dan's answer but didn't get very far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
FinalRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet4").Range(Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, "A"), Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(FinalRow, "K")).ClearContents

If Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, "A").Value = "" Then
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:K1").Copy
Sheets("Sheet4").Range(Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, "A"), Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, "K")).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End If

For x = 2 To FinalRow
    ThisValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "A").Value
    ThatValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, "D").Value
    If ThisValue = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, "B").Value And ThatValue = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, "D").Value Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 11)).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    NextRow = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Sheets("Sheet4").Range(Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(NextRow, 1), Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(NextRow, 11))
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
    .PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End With

    End If

    Next x

Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I have included my previous answer's changes into the full code block that is now provided below.

```
Sub Compiler()
 Dim i
 Dim LastRow, Pasterow As Integer
 Dim sht As Worksheet

   Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

   LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

  Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:J6768").ClearContents

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B3").Value And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D3").Value Then
           Pasterow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
           Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & Pasterow)
        End If
     Next i

 Sheets("sheet4").Rows(1).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: The error occurs in my if statement:  If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Values = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, "B").Values And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Values = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, "D").Values Then

Comment: I edited my answer to address your error. Typically **.Values** is usually used with declaring an array for series. **.Value** is used when referring to a cell's contents. Also, please check [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/291308) to see how to reference cells in various ways. You needed to be referencing the .Cells as .Range since you are using strings for reference rather than integers. For example, if it was .Cells(i, 1) then it would be ok, but since you used "A" it needed to be .Range("A" & i)

Comment: @danno161 `cells(i,"A")` is fine.

Comment: Thank you. It ran with no errors, however, it does not paste the rows that were filtered into sheet 4. Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: @findwindow, apologies, you are correct. I referenced an outdated page that does not contain all the ways to reference a cell, I am now informed!

Comment: @Eric, change the + sign to an & sign in '.range("A" & Rows.Count) and see if that works, I missed that change in my answer before

Comment: @Eric, I edited to provide my previous suggestions for changes in a more comprehensive answer. This one will make sure that data will not be overwritten when pasted. Also, the method I used deletes the first row since it will be skipped if the sheet is completely empty. Delete  'Sheets("sheet4").Rows(1).Delete'  if you wish to keep the first row in any circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").Values
Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(3, "B").Values
```

etc

You keep using `values`. Don't you mean `value`?